# WildFly - List of active session

Tags: wildfly

In my system I have 3 wildfly servers, balanced with a different tool.

I'm having a need to look the list of active sessions in wildfly, to look for specific users to identify in which server is the user logged (invalidate the session or to know which log I have to open).

I know that in the web console of wildfly, in "*Runtime -> Server -> Monitor -> Web -> Deployment -> app.war*" I can find the list of active sessions, but in the list is only show the columns of "*Session ID*", "*Creation time*" and "*Last accessed time*".

Is there a way to add a new column to the list, like a session variable?, or another way list the active sessions with more information?

And using wildfly 20 with centos 8, the three servers are running in standalone mode, but only temporarily, all are mean to be in domain mode.

Comment: Are you ok with putting this data outside of the Wildfly console?

Comment: It's a posibility